# Aren't the class outputs independent in the model trained with the multilabel dataset?

Tags: pytorch, recurrent-neural-network, loss-function, multilabel-classification

I'm trying to train a model that uses a Graph RNN structure. **The model was initially implemented as a single label and I had very successful results**. When I use the same dataset as a multilabel, I encounter a strange situation. First of all, I have 70 categories. And one of them is a category (0 category) that I want to be assigned in case the content cannot be assigned a category.

[image: True labels and prediction labels]

The model can really successfully assign 0 to non-category content. However, although it does not assign 0 in the content with a category, it does not make an assignment in other categories. What could be the reason for this? Also, when I try with 2 different data sets, I see that out of 70 categories in a dataset, only those belonging to "0" are estimated, and the rest are empty. Accuracy always reaches 78.23% and the model stalls at this point. In another data set, sometimes the predictions are correct and sometimes I see an empty assignment.

```
class Classifier(nn.Module):
def __init__(self, input_dim, hidden_size, tag_size, args, pred_type='SINGLE'):
    super(Classifier, self).__init__()
    self.emotion_att = MaskedEmotionAtt(input_dim)
    self.lin1 = nn.Linear(input_dim, hidden_size)
    self.drop = nn.Dropout(args.drop_rate)
    self.lin2 = nn.Linear(hidden_size, tag_size)
    self.pred_type = pred_type
    if args.class_weight:
        self.loss_weights = torch.tensor(torch.rand(tag_size) * 99 + 1).to(args.device)
        if self.pred_type == 'SINGLE':
            self.loss_func = nn.NLLLoss(self.loss_weights)
        elif self.pred_type == 'MULTI':
            self.loss_func = MultilabelLoss()
    else:
        if self.pred_type == 'SINGLE':
            self.loss_func = nn.NLLLoss()
        elif self.pred_type == 'MULTI':
            self.loss_func = MultilabelLoss()

def get_prob(self, h, text_len_tensor):
    # h_hat = self.emotion_att(h, text_len_tensor)
    # hidden = self.drop(F.relu(self.lin1(h_hat)))
    hidden = self.drop(F.relu(self.lin1(h)))
    scores = self.lin2(hidden)
    if self.pred_type == 'SINGLE':
        log_prob = F.log_softmax(scores, dim=-1)
    else:
        log_prob = F.sigmoid(scores)
    return log_prob

def forward(self, h, text_len_tensor):
    log_prob = self.get_prob(h, text_len_tensor)
    if self.pred_type == 'SINGLE':
        y_hat = torch.argmax(log_prob, dim=-1)
    elif self.pred_type == 'MULTI':
        y_hat = []
        for pred in log_prob:
            y_hat.append([1 if p > 0.5 else 0 for p in pred.flatten().tolist()])

        y_hat = torch.tensor(y_hat)
    try:
        y_hat
    except NameError:
        log.error('Prediction type should be one of these [\'SINGLE\', \'MULTI\']')
    return y_hat


def get_loss(self, h, label_tensor, text_len_tensor):
    log_prob = self.get_prob(h, text_len_tensor)
    loss = self.loss_func(log_prob, label_tensor)

    return loss
```